# CSS, overflow with safari, chrome and IE 6

Tags: css

Does safari and chrome support overflow? IE 6 or above, does it match with overflow correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You may want to look at this [CSS browser compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) (search for "overflow" in the page).

**Edit:** As stated in the chart,

> IE 5/6 doesn’t implement `overflow: visible` correctly.

Newer versions do.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is yes

The overflow property is supported in all major browsers.

Note: Internet Explorer does not support the property value "inherit".

link:
      http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Internet explore has problems with `overflow:hidden;` when the element has percentage dimensions. To fix this you need to also put a `position:relative;` on the element for it to work.